# Columnas de tabla html pierden su posición al ocultarlas y volver a mostrarlas

Tags: javascript, html

La función de ocultar columna funciona bien, pero cuando se ocultan varias y se quiere volver a mostrarlas se desacomodan y se apilan erróneamente.

```js
var tabla = new Object();

function alternar(columna) {
  var estado;
  if (tabla[columna] == 1) {
    tabla[columna] = 0;
    estado = 'block';
  } else {
    tabla[columna] = 1;
    estado = 'none';
  }
  var tbl = document.getElementById("tableMatrix");

  for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      if (j == columna)
        tbl.rows[i].cells[j].style.display = estado;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input onClick='alternar(0);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> a
  <input onClick='alternar(1);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> b
  <input onClick='alternar(2);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> c
  <input onClick='alternar(3);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> d
  <input onClick='alternar(4);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> e
  <input onClick='alternar(5);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> f
</form>
<table cellspacing="0" class="display" id="tableMatrix" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th>e</th>
      <th>f</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>gato</td>
    <td>perro</td>
    <td>vaca</td>
    <td>100,0000</td>
    <td>1000,0000</td>
    <td>234</td>
  </tr>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="footer">
      <td colspan="17"><input id="paginationKey" value="000" type="hidden" /><input id="pageSize" value="010" type="hidden" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer el error solo esta en el `display : block`, cambialo por `display : table-cell`:

```js
var tabla = new Object();

function alternar(columna) {
  var estado;
  if (tabla[columna] == 1) {
    tabla[columna] = 0;
    estado = 'table-cell';
  } else {
    tabla[columna] = 1;
    estado = 'none';
  }
  var tbl = document.getElementById("tableMatrix");

  for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      if (j == columna)
        tbl.rows[i].cells[j].style.display = estado;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input onClick='alternar(0);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> a
  <input onClick='alternar(1);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> b
  <input onClick='alternar(2);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> c
  <input onClick='alternar(3);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> d
  <input onClick='alternar(4);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> e
  <input onClick='alternar(5);' value='hide' type="checkbox" checked="checked" /> f
</form>
<table cellspacing="0" class="display" id="tableMatrix" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th>e</th>
      <th>f</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>gato</td>
    <td>perro</td>
    <td>vaca</td>
    <td>100,0000</td>
    <td>1000,0000</td>
    <td>234</td>
  </tr>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="footer">
      <td colspan="17"><input id="paginationKey" value="000" type="hidden" /><input id="pageSize" value="010" type="hidden" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```